# in django models how can i create view for boolean value in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i create a models for user in django models.py all i want is only when user Select true then save the form and redirect to page otherwise in other page without saving the form

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    yes = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Customer
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user','joined_date']
```

the view i created is just basic view i know it's not gonna work like that

views.py

```
def customer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return redirect('/Ecommerce/')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
        return render(request, 'customer.html', {'form': form})
```

my html

```
{% extends 'masteraccount.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootcss/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
{% endblock%}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      {{ form.yes|as_crispy_field }}
      <button type="submit"></button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why would the user even submit a form if they don't want to save / change something? Simply put an anchor to the other page for the user...

Comment: look for `form.cleaned_data.get('yes', False)`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i will do that later but firstly looking for answer

Comment: @Abhyudai will you please explain a bit